# How does Firefox update itself without asking for root/sudo password?

Tags: 20.04, permissions, firefox, policykit

How does Firefox update itself without asking for root/sudo password?

It's installed in `/usr`, where regular users don't have write permissions, and neither `/usr/bin/firefox`, nor any files in `/usr/lib/firefox` are `setuid`.

There must be some kind of daemon that runs with root permissions, ready to update Firefox, when asked?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason you do not need to enter sudo passwords for upgrades in modern systems is because these processes currently are managed through Polkit (formerly called PolicyKit). This is a mechanism that checks if a request, i.e. for updating, is authorized or not. That is defined through polkit rules.

Firefox is by default installed through the APT package management system. In Ubuntu 21.10, Firefox is installed as a Snap package. For most of the updates, the policy is configured such that these can be checked for and carried out while a user with root access is logged in, without an extra need to provide the `sudo` password. For kernel updates, the policy is set up to still require specifically entering the sudo password.